# SQL: Complex query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Entry-level SQL learner here.

Here is a snippet of my data. It contains the IDs of some orders, along with the IDs of the products within that order, and the IDs of all possible suppliers of that particular product. It's a result of inner joins, the data also exists in separate and less redundant tables.

My question is: how do I select the `Order_ID`s of all orders that have **at least** three different products that share **at least** one common supplier?
I have marked with asterisks the data that fulfills these criteria:

```
order_ID    product_ID  supplier_ID
10191*      00011       1088
10191*      00011       1212
10191*      00011       1774
10191*      00011**     3219***
10191*      00013       1212
10191*      00013**     3219***
10191*      00033       1001
10191*      00033**     3219***
10191*      00032       0061
102452      00013       1212
102452      00013       3219
102452      00027       1774
10297       00033       1001
10297       00033       3219
103067      00033       1001
103067      00033       3219
```

So the result should be simply

```
Order_ID
10191
```

Thank you in advance!

Here is the SQL code that gave birth to this table

```
 select
     OI.order_ID, S.product_ID, S.supplier_ID
 from 
     Orders_Items OI 
 inner join
     Supplies S on OI.product_ID = S.product_ID
 group by 
     OI.order_ID, S.product_ID, S.supplier_ID
```

Comment: You should post whatever query you are currently running to produce the output described and let us know exactly what is incorrect about the output it gives you.

Comment: What have you tried so far???????

Comment: I tried natural joining, and using COUNT, to no avail. Basically, my goal was to count how many times the most common Supplier_ID shows up for a particular order, and if that number is higher than 3, to retrieve the order_ID. The only thing I got is a disgraceful code.

Comment: Tag properly.  MySQL <> SQL Server.  You have tag for MySQL and SSMS.  Which dbms are you actually using?????

Comment: I have removed the MySQL tag. I am using SSMS

Comment: Title is misleading.  Was expecting a complex query.

Answer (score 0):

You could try applying a having on count(distinct product_id) >= 3 ond the query select result

```
  select t.order_id
  from ( 
        Select OI.order_ID, S.product_ID, S.supplier_ID
        from Orders_Items OI 
        INNER JOIN Supplies S on OI.product_ID=S.product_ID
        group by OI.order_ID, S.product_ID, S.supplier_ID) t
  group by t.order_id, t.supplier_ID
  having count(distinct t.product_id) >= 3
```

Comment: Yeah, that's it! Thank you very much. I am having trouble "translating" it though. You took my original table and then regrouped by columns I already used for grouping? How does that work?

Comment: That is call a `subquery` is like create a temporal table on the fly. In this case he call the subquery `t`

Comment: I have some experience with them ... But the logic here just baffles me! How can I have different results from grouping a table with the same columns? Thanks again!

Comment: well I think your original query the group isnt really doing much because you are grouping for all the columns. At most you could replace that as `DISTINCT`. But scais query only group for two fields instead of three and count the total of the third

Comment: then group by in the other  query is on two column only so you count the number of distinct inner product .. .. is simple  .. in the inner query you group by 3 column  ..

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza The original query grouping was to avoid some double rows, a result of the fact that one product can be supplied by the same supplier multiple times.

Comment: Well that sound like a design problem. Like you get 3 soda from supplierA and then 5 more soda from supplierA on the same order?

Comment: for avoid double rows  you should use distinct and not group by

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, Nope, on different dates. The problem arises from the fact that the data that connects the suppliers with the products are on another Order table.

Comment: @scaisEdge Thanks for the tip! Will do from now on.

Comment: well you didnt include that in the query. But again one order doesnt have multiple days. But hey if is working for you, I just think doesnt look as the normal design I have seem before.

Comment: It is a pretty strange design choice. However, the problem arose not because of 2 orders on the same day, but because one item could be purchased from the same supplier in a different date. For some reason, the result would be many duplicate rows.

Comment: That sound like a should be a different order.

Answer (score 0):

You probably will get the same result as scaisEdge with this query

```
 SELECT OI.order_ID
 FROM Orders_Items OI 
 INNER JOIN Supplies S 
    ON OI.product_ID=S.product_ID
 GROUP BY  OI.order_ID, S.supplier_ID
 HAVING COUNT(distinct t.product_id) >= 3
```